# Webform2pdf - Message body empty

Tags: webforms, files, emails

I'm trying to use webform2pdf to generate a pdf containing form inputs. The form works fine if I don't check "Generate PDF Document", and I receive a confirmation email.

If I do enable the PDF, I don't receive a confirmation email and I get the following error:

> Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists.

In the smtp log I see:

```
phpmailerException: Message body empty in PHPMailer->Send() (line 577 of /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/sites/all/modules/smtp/smtp.phpmailer.inc).
```

Is there additional configuration I need to make? Drupal is new to me.

- Drupal - 7.54
- Webform - 7.x-4.15
- Webform 2 PDF - 7.x-4.0
- SMTP Authentication Support - 7.x-1.6
- MIME Mail - 7.x-1.0
- TCPDF - 6.2.13

** Edit **

Turning off SMTP Authentication Support and using DefaultMailSystem solved this particular issue and allows PDF attachements, although DefaultMailSystem only allows plain text emails.

Answer (score 0):

Webform2PDF has dependencies, did you install them?

> **Third-party tools:**
>
> - TCPDF
>
>   - 4.5.000 or later required from webform2pdf 2.x or 3.x
>   - 6.0.000 or later required from webform2pdf 4.x

Comment: Sorry, forget to mention that. Yes, 6.2.13. Coped to sites/all/libraries/tcpdf rather than installed.

Comment: are there any errors messages in your php error log, dblog, etc. Check your server log files.

Comment: There are no errors in the server log files. Admittedly I added "error_log" to php.ini and it's not being picked up. It's definitely the right php.ini and it's not being overidden by .htaccess. As for the original issue, I have noticed the PDF files are being created, as I can view them via the CMS. So I guess that rules out any issue with TCPDF.

Comment: Turning off SMTP Authentication Support resolves the issue, and I can receive emails with PDF attachments if I use "DefaultMailSystem". I need HTML emails and "MimeMailSystem" doesn't seem to work, but that's a separate investigation

Comment: I recommend updating your question (if you can) with the details you've uncovered.